# Can (Aともかく,B.) be always understood as (Do do you know about A? B.)?

Tags: meaning, parsing

漢字を読むことはともかく、書くことは苦手だ。

1. I can't even write, let alone read Kanji.
2. Regardless whether i can read Kanji or not, I can't write it.

**Which translation is correct, *1)* or *2)*?**

<sub>The speaker **Confirms** their disability to 書く.</sub>

<sub>Is it also confirmed that they are able to 漢字を読む or is it left **unclear**????</sub>

<sub>How can i figure out the answer from the sentence?</sub>

Comment: You've been asking some interesting questions recently, which is great, but could I please ask you to put a little more thought into your question titles. Questions should benefit as many people as possible and many of your question titles don't really address the main problem that you have, so they aren't so helpful when it comes to searching for answers to problems. For example, this questions is about the use of ともかく, so a question title such "How to understand  ともかく", or something like that, would be much more helpful for future people looking for answers to problems similar to your own.

Comment: My bad, up until now, i was trying to make titles represent 'my own thought about the problem' with the hope that i get relevant & more accurate answers.
But in the other hand, i'd be thankful for useful edits to my questions using the "edit" button.

Answer (score 3):

The grammar point is `AはともかくB`, comparing two things but placing more emphasis on the importance of B in the current discussion. In English, it can be translated as something like `Whatever about A, B is..`. So the speaker is making sure that B is what is intended to be stressed at the moment.

> 漢字を読むことはともかく、書くことは苦手だ。
> Whatever about reading kanji, (the problem is) I'm not good at writing them.

So your translated sentence #2 is accurate (although "can't" is perhaps too strong).

Check out a more detailed explanation in the links below:

- https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F-wa-tomokaku-meaning/
- https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2019/02/22/jlptn2-grammar-tomokakutoshite/
- http://www.edewakaru.com/archives/20829461.html

Comment: わたしは、日本語を話すことはともかく、書く事は苦手だ。
I can’t even write Japanese, let alone speak it.
According to:
https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F-wa-tomokaku/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking in the comment

Comment: I ask for more explanation about why this site prefered to translate the sentence to:[I can’t even write Japanese, let alone speak it.] and not  the second translation.
Are the two translations interchangeable? Although in English they don't exactly have the same meaning i think.

Comment: They aren't different. The main focus is still B (I can't write), whatever about A (speaking it).

Comment: I'm proposing this 'more literal' translation:
[Do you know about speaking Japanese? I can't write it]
Like this it lets either of the two previous translations possible *even* in English.
But this step needs your supervision.

Comment: @raruna Where is the idea of a question coming from?

Comment: @raruna Sorry but your interpretation is not in line with the websites I listed explaining the grammar point. It's important to not focus on the English translation sometimes - it's often more helpful to internalize the meaning of the grammar point from natural Japanese example sentences, such as those listed on the sites.

Comment: @kandyman
1) Aは今は問題にしないでBだ。=with asking now about A, B.
2) Aについて考える必要があるが、今は(置いておいて?)Bを優先させる。=thinking about A is important, but now (putting it in place?), we make B a priority.

If my literal translation is correct, the first definition is somehow close to my proposed interpretation, isn't it?

Comment: @Leebo Sorry I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: @raruna you proposed "Do you know about speaking Japanese?" as a translation of 日本語を話すことはともかく, correct? The Japanese sentence has no aspect of being a question, so I was asking where that proposal was coming from.

Comment: @Leebo Ah, now i get it.

Since you are American, i'm relying on you to guide me with this:
"Do you know about A?" is not supposed to mean a question that asks for an answer. It's just an expression to attract the second-person to consider A. I thought it would be familiar to you though. :/
Another suggestion:
"Let's consider A, B."
[Let's consider speaking Japanese, I can't write it] how about this one?

BUT I don't mean [Let's consider (I can) speaking Japanese, I can't write it]!!!!!! not to misunderstand.

Comment: Making it a question or using "let's consider" both sound like you are drawing attention to that part, but the whole point of ともかく is that it marks something that is not what is going to be focused on